# Script not working getting a "Not Valid Identifier"

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Am doing this for a class, but am having issues with it.  I am new to Linux and really having a hard time.  Am trying input 3 values (M, R, T), figure out if they are greater, less than or equal to 2000 and print a statement.  Not sure I am doing it right.  I get the questions and can input, but am not sure if it is completely working.

```
#!/bin/sh
    clear
echo -n "What is the value of M?"
read $M
sleep 3
echo -n "What is the value of R?"
read $R
echo -n "What is the value of T?"
read $T
A=$M+$R+$T
if [ $A > "2000" ]
then
        echo "A is over 2000"
else
        echo "A is 2000 or less"
fi
```

Comment: Remove the `$` from the `read` lines.

Comment: did that but get "Evaluate_A: line 16: read: `A=1000+1000+20': not a valid identifier
A is 2000 or less"

Comment: `A=$M+$R+$T` does concatenation of strings. That's not what you want. Use `A=$((M+R+T))` to *add* and you are comparing with a string.. Use integer. or read Tom's answer ;-)

Comment: get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS: one day you'll write `PATH=foo` and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: I only use all caps in Linux as that is what the teacher wants.

Comment: If that's what your teacher says, I guess you've got to do what they say but I agree with glenn, capital letters should be reserved for shell internal parameters and environment variables. You can tell your teacher that they're wrong from me :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong here. Firstly, `read` takes the name of the variable without the `$`. Secondly, you can specify a prompt on the same line, so no need for all the separate `echo`s. Thirdly, in order to do a numerical comparison, you should be using `-gt`:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
read -p "What is the value of M?" M
sleep 3
read -p "What is the value of R?" R
read -p "What is the value of T?" T
A=$((M+R+T)) # different syntax here too
if [ "$A" -gt 2000 ]
then
    echo "A is over 2000"
else
    echo "A is 2000 or less"
fi
```

If you are using bash, another way to compare integers in bash is to use an arithmetic context:

```
if (( A > 2000 ))
```

Remember to change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` if you want to use bash features.

Comment: That's awesome.  I would never have gotten that, as we haven't learned about -gt.

Comment: I just edited to show another way that you can compare integers in bash.

Comment: Or even `if (( M+R+T > 2000 ))`

Comment: @Glenn can't use that have to have the A